# Isolate sub-string after a certain pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a line in a file like this:

```html
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 1 </TD></TR>
```

`monogram ended in` is always constant but not the `1`, this number changes always and can be up to a 3-digit number.

So I need a command to search for `monogram ended in`  and get the number after thit string.

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: The right answer will depend on what you want toi **do** with that sub-string after you isolate it. For example, with mandatory POSIX tools If you just want to print it then you'd use grep, sed, or awk, if you want to change it to a different string then sed or awk, if you want to perform arithmetic on it then awk.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -n 's/.*monogram ended in \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' filename
```

- with `-n`, you suppress normal output
- the `s`ubstitute command replaces the whole line (`.*` at beginning and end) by `\1`, which is the part inside `\(\)`, i.e. the number
- the `p` flag prints the substitution on a match

Answer (score 4):

The GNU implementation of grep has the `-P` option, which enables a set of regular expressions described as "Perl-compatible regular expressions".  These have `\K`, which can be used to reduce the output the way you're looking for:

```
grep -Po 'monogram ended in \K\d+' filename
```

- the `-P` option enables Perl-style regular expressions
- the `-o` option tells grep to output only the matching part of the line (not the whole line)
- the regular expression matches the line you describe, which is "monogram ended in " followed by numeric digits
- the `\K` expression tells grep to use the whole regular expression to match the line, but write out only the portion of the expression that follows the `\K`
- the `\d+` expression matches one or more digits

My example above doesn't limit the match to three consecutive digits.  If you want to do that, the expression that works best is:

```
grep -Po 'monogram ended in \K\d{1,3}(?!\d)' filename
```

- the `\d{1,3}` expression matches one, two, or three consecutive digits
- the `(?!\d)` expression looks to the position just after the digits to ensure it's not a digit (could be a character, or could be the end of the line), ensuring that lines with 4+ consecutive digits will not be matched

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'put $/ if m/ <?after "monogram ended in" \s > \d+ /;'
```

Raku is a good choice if you'll need to handle Unicode characters (robust Unicode support is built-in). The above prints `$/` (Raku's match variable, alternatively `$<>`). The code uses a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion ( `<?after … >` ), assumes one match per line, and drops non matching lines.

If you want blank lines where no matches are found, use the code below:

```perl
raku -ne 'if m/ <?after "monogram ended in" \s > \d+ / {put $/} else {put ""};'
```

You can restrict the range of matching digits using Raku's `**` regex quantifier, for example: `\d**1..3` or `<digits>**1..3` will only return matches that are 1-to-3 digits in length. But as lines are read left-to-right, matching lines with numbers longer than 3 digits will be truncated on the right end. Thus simply adding a quantifier may not give you the result you anticipate: to do this properly you'll have to add a non-digit regex atom at the right end:

```perl
raku -ne 'put $<> if m/ <?after "monogram ended in " > <digit>**1..3 <!digit> /;'
```

Sample Input:

```
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 1 </TD></TR>
<TD><TR> duogram ended in 2 </TD></TR>
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 4444 </TD></TR>
```

Sample Output (final code example): `1`

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (for the edited question):

```
sed -e 's@^<TD><TR> monogram ended in \([0-9]\{1,3\}\) </TD></TR>$@\1@;t' -e 'd' sample
```

---

For the original question, again with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -e '/monogram ended in /!d' -e 's///'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Perl:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/env perl
 2  use strict;
 3  use warnings;
 4  while (<>) {
 5      print($1, "\n")
 6          if /<TD><TR> monogram ended in (\d+) <\/TD><\/TR>/
 7  }
```

Line 1 lets the shell know this is a Perl script [1].

Line 2 "The strict pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could behave unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into errors. " [2]

Line 3 "The warnings pragma gives control over which warnings are enabled in which parts of a Perl program." [3]

Lines 4-7 form a while compound statement [4].

Line 4 the `while` loop expression uses the null filehandle `<>` (diamond operator) [5], allowing the solution to be used as a Unix filter [6]. For each line of input, `while` will assign the current line of input to the default input general variable `$_` [7] and evaluate `BLOCK`.

Line 5-6 form an `if` compound statement using statement modifier syntax [8].  If the regular expression [9] for the desired layout `/\<TD\>\<TR> monogram ended in (\d+) \<\/TD\>\<\/TR\>/` matches a line of input, the number is captured in global variable `$1` [10] and printed (followed by a newline).

Using the following input:

```
sd al;sdgalsdg lkajsdg asdgl;kjasldkgj lkasdjglk jasdg
asdgl;kjasdg asdg ;lkjasdg l;aksjdg opizxcjvbko qweqweopin
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 42 </TD></TR>
asdg;lkj asdg opiaxcpokmasdiopmnadg 
qa spdfkomnasd;klmasdopfjwqet
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 1 </TD></TR>
advpoaisejrta aerg lamspoiamwefop z;selgf aergl ,m
;lkasdg ;lkamsegop kmd,auriklasej e
<TD><TR> monogram ended in 5 </TD></TR>
```

The solution produces the following output:

```
$ perl solution.pl input.txt 
42
1
5
```

References:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

[2] https://perldoc.perl.org/strict

[3] https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings

[4] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements

[5] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I%2FO-Operators

[6] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)#Unix

[7] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#General-Variables

[8] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers

[9] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre

[10] https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$%3Cdigits%3E%20($1,%20$2,%20...)

Comment: Or `perl -lne 'print $1 if m{<TD><TR> monogram ended in (\d+) </TD></TR>}'` (`<` is not special in perl REs, no need for `\<`).

Comment: Thank you for the regex \< \> pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is XML and that the nodes are ordered in the correct way, as in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <TR>
    <TD>monogram ended in 1</TD>
  </TR>
</root>
```

(the start tags for the `TR` and `TD` nodes were swapped in the question), then we may use an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet` to extract the part of the value that occurs after `monogram ended in`  in any `TD` node that is a child node of a `TR` node like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel --template \
    --match    '//TR/TD[starts-with(text(),"monogram ended in ")]' \
    --value-of 'substring-after(text(),"monogram ended in ")' -nl file.xml
```

For each `TD` node that is an immediate child node of a `TR` node and has a value that starts with the string `monogram ended in` , this extracts the text after that string and then adds a newline.

For an example document like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <TR>
    <TD>monogram ended in 1</TD>
    <TD>monogram ended in 2</TD>
    <TD>monogram ended in 3</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>monogram ended in A</TD>
    <TD>monogram ended in B</TD>
    <TD>monogram ended in C</TD>
  </TR>
</root>
```

... the command would output

```
1
2
3
A
B
C
```